# Create a class without a constructor in .NET managed C++

Tags: .net, managed-c++

I want to create a class to hold my specific variable like a bitmap.
I must include this class and can use the bitmap without creating an instance of this class.

How can I do this?

Comment: normal class with a static member?

Comment: No static classes in C++/CLI.  Sure, a static member will work.  Same thing as a global variable.

Comment: @HansPassant - you make a static class in C++/CLI by marking it abstract sealed, same thing the CLR does for C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is assuming you meant C++/CLI and not managed C++, as they *are* fairly different languages.

```
public ref class MyStaticClass abstract sealed {
     // static members here
};
```

That will create a static class that can't be instantiated, holding whatever static members you need.

If your class will only be holding static data, I would recommend doing it this way, via a static class.  If you intend on letting the class be instantiated (it looks from your question that this isn't the case), you shouldn't declare it with `abstract sealed` and simply make the member you want to access without an instance, static.